# Sort rows in CSV from Java

Tags: java, date, csv

I need some ideas how to sort rows in CSV file from Java code. In particular, in the CSV file I have 5 columns, one of them is Date. So, I should sort from oldest to latest date. How to do this from Java?

Comment: How do you load your CSV file ? If you have a `List`, you can give a look at `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly is the problem? Reading the file? Reading the CSV into a data structure? Reading the date? Sorting the data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the approach:

> 1. Create a class lets say Record to represent your CSV data. Define attributes and getter and setters for them.
> 2. In your Record class implement Comparable and write the compareTo method. The signature of compareTo can be:
>
>    `public int compareTo(Record record)`
> 3. Inside compareTo, compare the dates of 'this' and input record object.
> 4. Read your csv file in a method lets say main method. Create a list of records representing each line of csv.
> 5. Finally call Collections.sort(listOfRecords);

Here is a good tutorial to help you understand Comparator and Comparable interfaces:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Hope it helps!